# Interpreting this sentence "I hope to have a written response to your concerns by the end of this week"

Tags: meaning, email

> I hope to have a written response to your concerns by the end of this week

So does it mean

1. the person hopes to **have something to give me** by the end of this week.

or

2. the person want **my response** by the end of this week.

Comment: What does “depict” mean?

Comment: to explain? to understand? what is the meaning? Let me know if there is a better title for this question

Comment: Who presented the concerns? And to whom? Anyway, depict means to show in a picture or drawing (to picture).

Comment: If the response will be to 'your' concerns (those of the person being addressed), presumably it's the speaker who is offering to provide it. (NB **a the** is presumably a typo.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Out of context, the scenario where you are meant to respond to your own concerns is awkward and not so likely to happen.

The response is ***to your concerns***. The other person is hoping to write that response ***to you*** by the end of this week. It is a promise that this person will try his/her best, but politely leaving a probability of not meeting the deadline this person sets for himself/herself.

Note: I would put *Interpreting* (not *depicting*) in the title of your question.